# Why constant variables inside functions fail to compile in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

Why does this fail to compile on Solidity?

```
contract TestContract {
    function testFunc() {
        int256 constant testVar = 1;
    }
}
```

It compiles if I remove the `constant` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Solidity only state variables can be declared as constant.

> State variables can be declared as constant. In this case, they have
>   to be assigned from an expression which is a constant at compile time

Ref: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#constant-state-variables

So just move the variable in the contract scope instead of function scope and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Because currently Solidity only accepts constant state variables for Strings and value types
like in the following example:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract C {
   unit constant x= 32**22 - 8;
   string constant text = "contract";
}
```

here is a link explaining variables, events & functions:
https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/solidity-variables

Answer (score 0):

so apparently solidity has disallowed the use of constant in functions afte version 0.5.0 this is the documentation. i have a very similar issue to yours and trying to fix it i will leave a comment here once found
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html
this is the specific page you're looking for.